# Spring hibernate маппинг большого запроса в Entity

Tags: java, sql, spring, hibernate, jpa

есть нативный запрос

```
select t1.*, t2.*, t3.*, ... , t10.*
from table1 t1
left join table2 t2 on t2.id = t1.id
left join table3 t3 on t3.id = t1.id2
left join table4 t4 on t4.id = t3.id
left join table5 t5 on t5.id = t3.id2
...
left join table10 t10 on t10.id = t9.id
```

работает и маппится ручками - быстро.
Пробовал, точнее начал, доставать все при помощb JPA, очень долго ,вложенные сущности достаются отдельными запросами, что и приводит к просадке производительности. Как можно это все собрать, возможно каким-то query builder'ом, что бы не маппить ручками? Что бы все доставалось одним запросом и маппилось в ентити?
Для примера, маппинг естественно везде навешан

```
@Entity
public class Table1 {
    private Table2 table2;
    private List<Table3> list;

}
@Entity
public class Table2 {
    Integer field1;
    Integer field2;
    Integer field3;
}
public class Table3 {
    String field1;
    String field2;
    String field3;
    Table4 table4;

}
@Entity
public class Table4 {
    String field1;
    String field2;
    String field3;
    String field4;
    Table5 table5;
}
... и так еще с десяток сущностей
```

Comment: Вам нужно в конкретную Entity? Можно просто создать view над таблицами - такую виртуальную Entity, которая будет доставаться таким запросом из базы, а сам запрос прописать в @Subselect аннотации над классом.

Comment: @iksuy да, необходимо в конкретную entity и что бы все вложенные  entities также подтянулись

Comment: То есть вам нужна Entity, а в ней поля с аннотациями @Many/OneToMany/One, верно? Тогда всё должно работать, нужно попробовать поиграть с @FetchType

Comment: @iksuy Да все верно, оно то работает, и с фетч тайп игрался, но все равно сущности третьеи и следующих вложенностей достаются отдельными запросами. И как результат все достается долго

Comment: Если начали писать ручками, то зачем тогда фреймворк?

Comment: @RomanC хочется что бы это не выглядело на столько монструозно плюс ко всему поддерживать такое детище будет сложнее нежели проапдейтить сущность

Comment: @jvic именно так оно и выглядит у вас сейчас.